# Is it possible to install Kaldi on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaldi

I want to use Google Colab in a research project using Kaldi ASR. Is it possible to install it? and Where Can I find Kaldi files after installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a notebook demonstrating the install steps for a managed backend:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rp2eZRHW9OYnA1WpRGeblG6fDSyyH-my

The install takes a while. You might want to do this once on your machine and use Colab's [local runtimes](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) support.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it into my `kora` library.

Now you can install kaldi and pykaldi with just 2 lines of code.

```py
!pip install kora -q
import kora.install.kaldi
```